# Remote (RDP) utility with mstscax.dll

Tags: vb.net, remote-desktop, rdp

I am looking for information on using mstscax.dll in VB. The goal is to create a utility that logs into a remote service in the same manner as remote desktop. However, my utility is not required to show the desktop.

I have a series of commands that I will start off with that will look for users, reset logins, shadow, and message. I have been using a batch file on my RDP to perform these functions, but we are already looking for more functionality and power than what the batch commands can offer.

I am googling 'mstscax.dll' but the results have been less than satisfactory although I continue to search. Does anyone have any good references? Is this even going to be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to list or perform operations on remote desktop sessions, you might find the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) helpful. The library can list users logged on to a server, disconnect or logoff sessions, shadow sessions, and display message boxes in a session, among other things. (Note that the shadowing functionality requires a pre-release version of the library available on the project's [build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project51) -- use the artifacts link.)

Comment: Very nice. I'll look into it a little more. But at this point, looks like Cassia will be what I'm looking for. Regardless, yes, the functions you listed are exactly what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to use the msrdp.ocx control rather than that dll, though I've personally never used either so can't say for sure.

Edit: Add link

Here's a codeproject article about automating RDP:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET.aspx