# what happens on port 2179?

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

Is there any way to code my own console client for hyper-v guest machines ?
I don't want to connect to guest using RDP. I would like to do it in same way Microsoft is doing it.

What I've found so far is (correct me if I am wrong):
Their client connects to the host on port 2179. Then some handshaking, metadata exchange happens on port 2179 and client gets data on some 49xxx port.

What I don't understand is what happens on port 2179 ? Is there any protocol specification I should look for ?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed someone voted here so just for anyone who is reaching here from search: Check MS-RDPEPS for specification. Also, if your goal is to get console of hyper-v guest in third party client, FreeRDP has that support.
This thread can be buried now. 
- Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of Googling on `Hyper-V` and `2179` led me to `vmconnect.exe`, a program used to connect to virtual machines running on Hyper-V servers.

This tool is [stated](http://fawzi.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/virtual-machine-connection/) to use the Remote Desktop Protocol.

So I guess you can connect using the [RDP API itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383494(v=vs.85).aspx) (`mstscax.dll`), the [`Cassia`](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) library (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936051/266143) answer) or the [ActiveX control `AxMSTSCLib`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET).

Comment: Thanks ! if it is just RDP then if I try to connect on port 2179 using some other RDP client, it doesn't work. any idea why is it so ?